# Can I Enter a Command on More than One Line in a Command Prompt Window or Script?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script

I have a long command line, and I would like to enter it on several lines. Something like the following (if it were possible):

```
vsdbcmd /a:Deploy /manifest:Database.deploymanifest _
    /p:DeploymentConfigurationFile=Database_Database.sqldeployment _
    /p:SqlCommandVariablesFile=Database_Database.sqlcmdvars _
    /p:TargetDatabase=Database _
    /dd- /cs:"Data Source=production;integrated security=true" _
    /script:DatabaseChanges.sql /dsp:SQL > errors.log 2>&1
```

Is there a character or sequence of characters that can be used to write a command line on more than one line?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if it's more than one line, and looks as long and as complicated as you specified, why not put it in a bat/cmd file, or better yet, a script (wsh/poweshell)? This would allow you to launch it with one word

Comment: I intend to put it into a script, but will it run if it's on more than one line?

Comment: That is the point of a script/batchfile

Comment: The closest I can see,  and it's not for a cmd prompt window but powershell window works for a powershell script too, is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608144/how-to-split-long-commands-over-multiple-lines-in-powershell

Comment: He clearly wants good formatting, so it's very readable. He asked how to do it in a script in his title too.

Comment: I put the above into a .cmd file, without the "_", and it doesn't work (which is what I expected). Each line executes as a single command line.

Comment: @John Saunders cmd is like bat, I don't think you can.  Powershell you can. Or you could do 1 bat file with the command, then to run it you strip the new lines like | tr -d '\r\n'. | cmd. so could use 2 bat files. but it looks like you want clarity/simplicity/readability, prettyness/ a modicum of elegance like in a proper programming language. What I would suggest, is word wrap, to read the command. And a multi-line comment (I think bat files do them between % signs) the multi-line comment could have the whole command on multiple lines so you can read it better

Comment: doesnt backslash before a return escape it, even in cmd?  my windows-fu is a bit rusty...

Comment: There are examples here that may work... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx

Comment: @peelman  NT CMD's escape character is ^ not backslash. I'm not sure about MS-DOS. I do remember  in ms-dos ansi.sys prompt .. $e[  to initiate an ansi escape sequence! not sure though outside of the prompt command. But see cmd /? it mentions caret. the backslash at the end of a line  which you mention, does ring a little bell, but that could be from linux or something.

Comment: @barlop that's what it was.  in Bash its \. I can think of a couple of shells that use something different.  Was on the iPad when I commented, so my testing abilities were limited at best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using '^' as the continuation character. For example:

```
echo foo ^
bar ^
baz
```

results in:

```
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I first used DOS back in 1983 and never knew this. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I assume it's documented somewhere but I couldn't tell you where I first saw it. (It also works for escaping '>', '<', and '|'.)

Comment: neat!  I never knew this existed.